# Slick 3.2.1 Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am using Slick 3.2.1

This is my code

```
println(s"select id from foo where email_address='${foo.emailAddress}' and id = 700")
val existsQuery = sql"""select id from foo where email_address='${foo.emailAddress}' and id = 700""".as[Long]
val result = Await.result(mysqlDbWrite.run(existsQuery), Duration.Inf).isEmpty
println(s"result ${result}")
```

This code first prints

```
select id from foo where email_address='foo@yahoo.com' and id = 700
```

and then throws the error

```
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

But you can see clearly that I don't have any `?` in my query. Nor am I setting any parameters. So why am i getting this error?

Comment: Don't put `'${foo.emailAddress}'` in single quotes. Slick will see `${foo.emailAddress}` as a parameter passed to the query and rewrite it as `'?'`. However, as it's inside single quotes, the SQL database will see as comparing the `email_address` column to a `'?'` string, which does not count as a parameter. Just write it as `email_address = ${foo.emailAddress}`.

Comment: yes that worked. can you please reply as an answer rather than comment. so that I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

As Marth Pointed out you have to delete the single quotes, Slick does the placement by itself. Just place the parameters as is

Instead of `'${foo.emailAddress}'` just write `${foo.emailAddress}`